# Tensorflow mirrored strategy error: Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel( SwapDimension1And2InTensor3UsingTiles)

Tags: python

I am running a 3D U-net model for segmentation, and came across this error:

Detailed error:

```
GpuLaunchKernel( SwapDimension1And2InTensor3UsingTiles<T, kNumThreads, 
kTileSize, kTileSize, conjugate>, total_tiles_count, kNumThreads, 0, 
d.stream(), input, input_dims, output) status: Internal: 
invalid configuration argument
```

Aborted (core dumped)
The model works fine on a single GPU, I don't know why it throws error for multiple GPUs. I tried altering the architecture and the datagen methods, but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. when you use tensorflow mirrored strategy the batch_size specified in the `fit` function become a global batch size. so you must make sure that the `batch size` is **divisible** by the **number of gpus** used.

Comment: Thank you! I had a batch size of 1, since it is a volumetric data, and when I increased it to 4 (i.e. the global BS =4) it worked fine! (I ran it on 4 GPUs).